# add custom field in woocommerce edit address page

Tags: woocommerce, field, checkout, billing

I have added a custom field to woocommerce checkout billing field. I want to add that custom field to edit address page from where user can update that field, which comes when user is logged in.

How to achieve this? Eg: I have to add a field before phone field on edit address page.

Comment: this is for account page, I want to add custom fields to my edit address page where billing address fields are shown. However, above mentioned link does not show fields even on edit account page

Comment: This is not duplicate. Your code only adds fields to `edit-account` page but not in -`edit-address` @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43343519/8913606

Comment: You need to use `woocommerce_billing_fields` and `woocommerce_shipping_fields` hooks for both checkout and my account edit adresses… The fields that appear in checkout will appear also in my account edit adresses. This has been answered a lot of times yet… so it's a duplicate as you don't provide any code or enough details.